# Writing to custom ouput file with lualatex: Hook to start of the writing process and substitute not-fully expandable macros

Tags: luatex, expansion, write, callback

I am working on writing document with informations, that are at the end of each part summarized in summary. To prevent writing them twice, I am using `datatool` to create "buffers" in runtime, from which the informations are again retrieved and reprinted when I need them.

Now I am also facing requirement to be able to output the contents of these "`datatool` buffers" to an custom file. From information of a previous question in this matter (which wasnt constructed well and I asked for its deletion) I know, that some commands cannot be fully expanded. Since I am using LuaLaTeX for typesetting, I would like to know if it is possible to hook somehow to the writing process (with proper callback) and to subtitute unexpandable command with theyre expandable variants (or remove them from "buffer to be written to file").

Those commands are in particular: `\textbf` and `textit` (remove from writing to file), `\gls` from glossaries (retrieve the abbreviation) and also removing the function `pevnaMezera` from callback. This writes rubbish to file as well. The last part I tryed to do naively in line 25 and 27, but did not succeeded.

So my question is: Is there a way (with LuaTeX or TeX facilities) to hook to file-writing process and preprocess the buffer of tokens to be written to file in such a way, that some will be fully expanded and unexpandable commands will be replaced with fitting alternatives?

MWE (a bit lengthy):

```
\documentclass [a4paper, 11pt, twoside, openright, czech]{scrbook}

\usepackage [czech,shorthands=off] {babel}                          
\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage{datatool}

\DTLnewdb{testdb}

\DTLaddcolumn{testdb}{system}
\DTLaddcolumn{testdb}{dotaz}

\newwrite\testdboutput
\immediate\openout\testdboutput=objections.txt

\newcommand{\objection}[2]{%
#2
\DTLnewrow{testdb}
\DTLnewdbentry{testdb}{status}{#1}
\DTLnewdbentry{testdb}{text}{#2}
\ifboolexpr{ test {\ifstrequal{1}{#1}}}%
{%TRUE
%\begin{stopcallback}
\immediate\write\testdboutput{#2}
%\end{stopcallback}
}%
{%FALSE
\relax%
}%
}

\usepackage{luacode}

\begin{luacode}
function pevnaMezera(s)
  s = string.gsub(s, " a ", " a~")
  return s
end

function startcallback()
luatexbase.add_to_callback("process_input_buffer", pevnaMezera , "pevnaMezera" )
end

function stopcallback()
   luatexbase.remove_from_callback("process_input_buffer", "pevnaMezera" )
end
\end{luacode}

\newenvironment{stopcallback}{\directlua{stopcallback()}}{\directlua{startcallback()}}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \directlua{luatexbase.add_to_callback(
  "process_input_buffer", pevnaMezera , "pevnaMezera" )}
}

\usepackage{varioref}
\usepackage[pdfencoding=auto]{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\usepackage[xindy={language=czech, codepage=utf8}, automake, nomain, abbreviations,% create "abbreviations" glossary
                    stylemods=longbooktabs% do the adjustments for the longbooktabs styles
                    ]{glossaries-extra}                     

\setabbreviationstyle{long-short}

\newacronym{hr}{HR}{health report}

\makeglossaries

\begin{document}
\section{First section}
\label{sec:first}

\objection{2}{Test objection not output in output file - objections.txt}

\objection{1}{Test objection; should be output into - objections.txt}

\clearpage

\section{Second section}

\objection{1}{Test objection with a abbreviation \gls{hr} and quotation \enquote{marks}. There are also some citations created with custom citation command.}

%\objection{1}{I found out, that using \textit{italics} and referencing \pageref{sec:first} exceeds tex capacity. Why?The objections contain those too.}

\closeout\testdboutput
\end{document}
```

**EDIT:**
After searching through LuaTeX documentation I have found out about callback `process_output_buffer`, which processess files output by TeX (except for `.log`), which is what could help me in this matter. However, if there is still any solution that would somehow get me closer to the state of letters shipped out to page, I would be very much happy to know.

I have also changed MWE (below) according to comments. Adding `unexpanded` helps in the manner allowing me to process output file to strip out commands and substitute them in means of `str.gsub`; but its more manual then (somehow) get only the actual letters shipped out to `.pdf`.

Edited MWE:

```
\documentclass [a4paper, 11pt, twoside, openright, czech]{scrbook}

\usepackage [czech,shorthands=off] {babel}                          
\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage{datatool}

\DTLnewdb{testdb}

\DTLaddcolumn{testdb}{system}
\DTLaddcolumn{testdb}{dotaz}

\newwrite\testdboutput
\immediate\openout\testdboutput=objections.txt

\newcommand{\objection}[2]{%
#2
\DTLnewrow{testdb}
\DTLnewdbentry{testdb}{status}{#1}
\DTLnewdbentry{testdb}{text}{#2}
\ifboolexpr{ test {\ifstrequal{1}{#1}}}%
{%TRUE
\immediate\write\testdboutput{\unexpanded{#2}}
}%
{%FALSE
\relax%
}%
}

\usepackage{luacode}

\begin{luacode}
function pevnaMezera(s)
  s = string.gsub(s, " a ", " a~")
  return s
end

function stripoutput(s)
  s = string.gsub(s, "~", " ")
  return s
end

function startcallback()
luatexbase.add_to_callback("process_input_buffer", pevnaMezera , "pevnaMezera" )
end

function stopcallback()
   luatexbase.remove_from_callback("process_input_buffer", "pevnaMezera" )
end
\end{luacode}

\newenvironment{stopcallback}{\directlua{stopcallback()}}{\directlua{startcallback()}}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \directlua{luatexbase.add_to_callback(
  "process_input_buffer", pevnaMezera , "pevnaMezera" )}
    \directlua{luatexbase.add_to_callback(
  "process_output_buffer", stripoutput , "stripoutput" )}
}

\usepackage{varioref}
\usepackage[pdfencoding=auto]{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\usepackage[xindy={language=czech, codepage=utf8}, automake, nomain, abbreviations,% create "abbreviations" glossary
                    stylemods=longbooktabs% do the adjustments for the longbooktabs styles
                    ]{glossaries-extra}                     

\setabbreviationstyle{long-short}

\newacronym{hr}{HR}{health report}

\makeglossaries

\begin{document}
\section{First section}
\label{sec:first}

\objection{2}{Test objection not output in output file - objections.txt}

\objection{1}{Test objection; should be output into - objections.txt}

\clearpage

\section{Second section}

\objection{1}{Test objection with a abbreviation \gls{hr} and quotation \enquote{marks}. There are also some a citations created with custom citation command.}%druhé ``a'' je na konci řádku

%\objection{1}{I found out, that using \textit{italics} and referencing \pageref{sec:first} exceeds tex capacity. Why?The objections contain those too.}

\closeout\testdboutput
\end{document}
```

Comment: What are you wanting to appear in the output file?

Comment: Same output text, as gets to pdf. Example: `A\textbf{BC}` should output `ABC`; `A\gls{hr}` should output `AHR` and similarly. I try to deal with citations differently since they are managed by custom citation command. The obvious alternative is copy text from `pdf` to `.txt`, but that makes the work lengthy and highly manual, since I would have to deal with manual line-endings.

Comment: Just do `\immediate\write\testdboutput{\unexpanded{#2}}`.  That should do the trick.

Comment: @HenriMenke Edited MWE according to your comment. Adding `unexpanded` gets me to other side of the TeX process, if I understand it correctly. Now the output file contains exactly the same as TeX input buffer before expansion, right? Meaning, I still have `\gls{hr}` and such commands in the output file. In meantime, I have found out about `process_output_buffer` callback, which would allow me to deal with these (unwanted) control sequences, but for my case its pretty suboptimal, since I have to write a bunch of `str.gsub` procedures ...  Could there be something more handy?